# What will be the output if the argument's date type is different?

Tags: java, overloading

What happens  if the actual parameter and formal parameter's data types are different in overloading   ?

```
Class A
{
   public void m1(int i)
    {
    System.out.println("int");
     }
     public void m1(float f)
     {
     System.out.println("float");
     }
 Public static void main(String[] args)
 {
  A a=new A();
  a.m1('a');
  a.m1(10l);
  }
  }
```

Comment: As long as your writing code just to make your question clear, why not indent it clearly?

Comment: Your code does not compile. Please provide a minimal working example (see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why not just run your program and see what happens?

Comment: @SteveSmith Good suggestion, because then OP would find that the code doesn't even compile, like dunni commented, and perhaps learn something too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In overloading method resolution if the matched method with specific argument is not available the compiler won't raise any error immediately,
First it promotes the argument to the next level and check for matched method.
1)If the matched method is available then it will be considered and if it is not available then compiler once again promotes this argument to the next level.
2)This process will be continued until all  the possible promotions still if the matched method is not available.Then only we will get compile error.
3)This is called **automatic promotion** in overloading.
The following are the possible promotions in java
Byte->short/char->int->long->
float->double

Comment: The reverse order is impossible in this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

The function corresponding to the arguments types gets called, this is some the basics of OOP not only in java but in all other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The method with the closest matching valid signature gets called.  This could well be a direct match (e.g. exactly the same function argument types), or (as in your code) the runtime knows how to automatically convert the char `a` to an int, so the method with the `int` param is called.